# Fake data for django channels unit tests

Tags: django, database, unit-testing, django-channels, django-testing

I previously asked a question regarding this topic but finally I gave up on that because there seemed to be no way ...

But now I really really really need to write unit tests for my django channel consumers because the application is growing larger in size and manual testing isn't efficient anymore. So I decided to ask another question and this time I'm going to do my best to explain the situation.

The main problem is **"Generating Fake Data"**. I'm using `factory_boy` and `faker` together in order to generate fake data for my tests. When I generate fake data, it is accessible from inside the `TestCase` itself but is not accessible inside the consumer. Let me show you by an example, consider the code below:

### test_consumers.py

```
from chat.models import PersonalChatRoom
from users.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from users.tests.test_setup import TestUtilsMixin
from astra_backend.asgi import application
from chat.tests.model_factory import PersonalChatRoomFactory


class TestPersonalChatRoomConsumer(TestCase, TestUtilsMixin):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        super().setUp()
        self.chat_room = PersonalChatRoomFactory()
        self.u1 = self.chat_room.user_1
        self.u2 = self.chat_room.user_2
     -> print("setup: (user): ", User.objects.all())
     -> print("setup: (personal chat room): ", PersonalChatRoom.objects.all())

    async def test_personal_chat_room_connection(self):
     -> await sync_to_async(print)("test (user): ", User.objects.all())
     -> await sync_to_async(print)("test (personal chat room): ", PersonalChatRoom.objects.all())

        com = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f'chat/personal/{self.chat_room.pk}/')
        connected, _ = await com.connect()
        self.assertTrue(connected)
```

### consumers.py

```
...
class PersonalChatConsumer(
        ChatRoomManagementMixin,
        MessageManagementMixin,
        JsonWebsocketConsumer
    ):
    message_serializer_class = PersonalMessageSerializer
    chat_room_class = PersonalChatRoom

    def connect(self):
     -> print("consumer (user): ", User.objects.all())
     -> print("consumer (personal chat room): ", PersonalChatRoom.objects.all())
        return super().connect() # some magic here
    
    ...
```

## output

I'm printing out the contents of the database in 3 different sections of the code:

- inside the `setUp` method in the `TestPersonalChatRoomConsumer` class
- inside the `test_personal_chat_room_connection` method in the `TestPersonalChatRoomConsumer` class
- inside the `connect` method of the consumer

I expected the results to be identical but here is the real output when running the test:

```
setup: (user):  <QuerySet [<User: joshua03@cervantes.net>, <User: pgolden@cummings.com>]>
setup: (personal chat room):  <QuerySet [<PersonalChatRoom: PV joshua03@cervantes.net and pgolden@cummings.com>]>
test (user):  <QuerySet [<User: joshua03@cervantes.net>, <User: pgolden@cummings.com>]>
test (personal chat room):  <QuerySet [<PersonalChatRoom: PV joshua03@cervantes.net and pgolden@cummings.com>]>

...

consumer (user):  <QuerySet []> # There are no users in the database
consumer (personal chat room):  <QuerySet []> # There are no chat rooms in the database
```

As you can see, the first section contains the fake data generated by `factory_boy` but the second section **contains an empty queryset**

## How to reproduce the problem

It is really simple:

1. create a simple model
2. create a consumer
3. create a test case and create an instance of that model inside tests
4. try to access the newly created instance inside the consumer and you'll be surprised with an empty queryset.

#### Why isn't the data generated inside `setUp` method accessible inside the consumer?

Here is what I think causes the problem personally:

- there might be something wrong with database transactions
- maybe it is about database connections
- maybe the consumer is using another database

if you need more information please leave a comment down below. I will provide all of them as soon as possible. Thank you all.

## Github minimal example

I have provided the most basic project that demonstrates the problem so that you don't have to reproduce it yourself.

Here is the link: **[REPO](https://github.com/Amohammadi2/channels-testing-example)**

extra info:

- database: postgresql v13 (psycopg2 backend)
- OS: Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) ubuntu 20.04
- python interpreter version: 3.8.10

### Edit

Here is the code for `PersonalChatRoomFactory`:

```
class PersonalChatRoomFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonalChatRoom

    user_1 = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    user_2 = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
```

It doesn't do anything that much, its purpose is to only create 2 users for `user_1` and `user_2` fields. Here is the code for `UserFactory`:

```
user_pass = 'somepassword'

class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: faker.unique.first_name())
    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: faker.unique.email())
    full_name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: faker.name())
    bio = factory.Sequence(lambda n: faker.text())
    date_verified = timezone.now()
    
    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Just hashes the raw password when creating the user """
        user =  super()._create(model_class, *args, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(kwargs.get('password', user_pass))
        user.save()
        return user
```

### Edit 2

Here is the code for my `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = CidField()
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    flagged_by = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, related_name='flagged_users')
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-images/', blank=True, null=True)
    date_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_woman = models.BooleanField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    major = models.ForeignKey(Major, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='users')
    date_verified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    verification_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date_verification_sent = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    can_own_movement = models.BooleanField('can user own a movemnet',default=False)
    online_devices = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
    # ... (some convenience methods and dynamic properties)
```

And it has a custom manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('email field is required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = password
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        password = make_password(password)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And here is the code for the `PersonalChatRoom` model:

```
class PersonalChatRoom(models.Model):
    user_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='personal_chat_rooms')
    user_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='personal_chat_room_contacts')
    visibility_stat = models.IntegerField(default=ChatRoomVisibilityStat.BOTH)

    def clean(self) -> None:
        if (not self.pk and self.are_users_connected(self.user_1, self.user_2)):
            raise ValidationError(
                "a chat room already exists between these two users", code="room_already_exists")
        return super().clean()
    # ... (some convenience methods)
```

Comment: share your factory script where you configure fake data

Comment: OK, I added the code for my fake factories @Sabil

Comment: Could you please add the models too?

Comment: Of course, now they have been added.

Comment: In you codes I can't find any trace of `def connect(self)`, where did you call this function in test?

Comment: It will be automatically called when the communicator tries to connect to the consumer `com = WebsocketCommunicator(application, f'chat/personal/{self.chat_room.pk}/')`. You can find this line of code in the test

Comment: Now I have added a minimal github repo that demonstrates the problem. @Sabil

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will check and try to solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue:** You face this data missing issue because of **asynchronous** calls.

**Solution:** In **django.test** there is a test class called **TransactionTestCase**. By using this we can overcome that **asynchronous** data missing issue.

**Make following changes and you are all set to go:**

#### test.py

Replace `TestCase` with `TransactionTestCase` and you are all set to go.

```py
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
class TestTheTestConsumer(TransactionTestCase):
```

**Output:**

```sh
python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
User (test.setUp):  <QuerySet [<User: someuser1>, <User: someuser2>]>
User (test.test_users_are_listed_correctly):  <QuerySet [<User: someuser1>, <User: someuser2>]>
User (consumer.connect):  <QuerySet [<User: someuser1>, <User: someuser2>]>
User (consumer.send_user_list):  <QuerySet [<User: someuser1>, <User: someuser2>]>
User (results):  [{'username': 'someuser1', 'id': 1}, {'username': 'someuser2', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: That was awesome! I tested it and it worked! I would absolutely give you the 50 reputation if you explain the magic behind `TransactionTestCase` and the way it helps solving the problem. What is problematic with `TestCase` and how `TransactionTestCase` solves that problem? What is the difference between these two and what makes `TransactionTestCase` fit for this kind of situations?

Comment: You can read this doc. After reading if you can't clarify your doubts then please ask me and i will clarify those. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase

Comment: OK. I checked it out but didn't understand anything . I think the difference is that `TransactionTestCase` commits to the database and at the end of each test, resets it back completely, whereas `TestCase` wraps the tests inside a transaction and rolls it back at the end of each test. Anyways, I applied your solution to my real project and it worked really well. Thank you for investing your time to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome and your assumption is correct. Keep learning. :)